# How to use plane sweep method to calculate intersect points between two circular arc polygons?

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, graphics, geometry

The traditional polygon can be represented by a series of vertexes.But I need to handle polygon with arcs, which edge may be line segment or circular arc. that looks like this:

[image]

As I know, the plane sweep method needs to sort all the endpoints of segments and put them into a heap, then use a red-black tree to manage the edges sorted by the y-axis. I find a paper which describes a method to deal with this case, but I have some confusion on the plane sweep algorithm part.The paper does not specifically describe how to place arc edges in red-black tree. This is the paper: [https://www.cs.sjtu.edu.cn/~yaobin/papers/tr_EBCAP.pdf](https://www.cs.sjtu.edu.cn/%7Eyaobin/papers/tr_EBCAP.pdf)?

And this is algorithm part:
[image]

Thanks for any discussion or help!

Comment: It seems you just add then like other segments, using the point of intersection with the sweep line as the key,